# Partial Derivatives for Sum of Squared Errors

Tags: calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, data-analysis

I have a simple, affine equation of the form $$ y = mx + b $$

I am using this equation to model some real-life data, and am accumulating the sum of squared errors, as per the formula:

$$ SSE(m, b) =\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - (mx_i + b))^2 $$

I would like to optimize the parameters *m* and *b*. Are below the correct partial derivatives? I would like to preserve summation if possible.

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial m} SSE = 2 \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - (mx_i + b))$$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial b} SSE = 2 \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - (mx_i + b))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As specified by the chain rule of differentiation, each of the terms in the sum must first be multiplied by the relevant partial derivative of (y - m*x - b), and only then added up.

For correct answers, see end of page 1 of [this PDF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://stat.math.uregina.ca/~kozdron/Teaching/Regina/252Winter05/Handouts/least_squares.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwimqZ3n4KnoAhWTK80KHQUuAL8QFjAKegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw304bqykGPm6YBb3KHdMosy&cshid=1584731500594).

Comment: Thanks, this answers it -- I forgot about the chain rule, and that the sum of derivatives is the same as the derivative of a sum.